# How to fill matrix with variable numbers?

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I need to fill matrix r, where `r=r(z)`, and `ri` is constant. But with this code I only get the first row where `r=-0.7:0.7`.

```
z=-1:0.001:0;
ri=0.7;
R=ri-z*(ri-1);
for z=-1:0.001:0;
r=(linspace(-(ri-z*(ri-1)),ri-z*(ri-1),1001))
end
```

`meshgrid` also does not work because it gives constant values on the end of the rows

My full matrix need to be in this shape, or transpose of this:

```
-0.7......  0.7

0.8  ...    0.8
.            .
.            .
.            .
0 .9 ...     0.9
.            .
.            .
.            .
1     ...    1
```

or

```
0   ......  0.7
0    ...    0.8
.            .
.            .
.            .
0  ...      0.9
.            .
.            .
.            .
0     ...    1
```

Comment: You are overwritting the value of `r` every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ander Biguri said, the problem is that each pass through the loop sets `r` and overwrites whatever was there from the previous pass. At the end of the loop you get the last row (not the first). Pre-allocate `r`

```
r = zeros(numel(z), 1001);
```

Then loop as

```
for k=1:numel(z)
   R=ri-z(k)*(ri-1); 
   r(k,:) = linspace(-R, R, 1001);% <-- Different row each pass
end
```

Hope this helps,

JAC